# search data from bean using JAX-RS Search issue

Tags: java, rest

```
import java.util.List;    
import javax.ws.rs.GET;    
import javax.ws.rs.Path;    
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;    
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.SearchCondition;    
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.search.SearchContext;    
import com.f2s.bean.Recentbean;

 @Path("search") 
   public class SearchResource {
      private List<Recentbean> ra;

    @Path("book")
    @GET
    public List<Recentbean> findBooks(@Context SearchContext searchContext) 
 {
     SearchCondition<Recentbean> condition = searchContext.getCondition(Recentbean.class);                 
    return condition.findAll(ra);
 }
```

error  :-  annotated with GET of resource, class com.f2s.restws.SearchResource, is not recognized as valid resource method.

com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you "question" is actually not a question. You're just presenting an error that you get. No explanation, no expected behaviour, no question asked. Providing some more details would be helpful.

Secondly, have you had a look on the other questions dealing with the presented exception? Here there are a few:

[Exception :com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161285/exception-com-sun-jersey-spi-inject-errorserrormessagesexception)

[Jersey: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376932/jersey-com-sun-jersey-spi-inject-errorserrormessagesexception)

[Errors$ErrorMessagesException when using Jersey in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578642/errorserrormessagesexception-when-using-jersey-in-java)

Because of my reputation I couldn't add this as a comment...